# Oracle: How do I only return the rows of the 2nd union if they exist?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have two selects combined with union in Oracle. I just want to return the rows of the 2nd union, if it returns anything, even though the 1st union might also be returning rows.

I was thinking about using nvl but I'm not sure how to implement it.

```
select 1 seq,
       x coord1,
       y coord2,
       z coord3
  from tableA a
 where a.prodRef = 4711
 union
select 2 seq,
       a coord1,
       b coord2,
       c coord3
  from tableB b
 where b.prodRef = 4711
```

Now the select returns rows from the queries with seq 1 and seq 2. If there's an output from the query with seq 2, I just want to see these data (excluded seq 1 rows), however, there might be cases in which seq 2 might return null rows. Of course, I just take the data of seq 1 in this case.

Do you guys have any ideas how to solve this? My mind is completely empty.

Comment: Add a not exists condition to the first select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select 2 as seq, a as coord1, b as coord2, c as coord3
from tableB b
where b.prodRef = 4711
union all
select 1 as seq, x as coord1, y as coord2, z as coord3
from tableA a
where a.prodRef = 4711 and
      not exists (select 1 from tableB b where b.prodRef = a.prodRef);
```